# Excel code .Address function in conditional formatting VBA

Tags: excel, vba, conditional-formatting

Thank you in advance,
I am trying to make conditional formatting by using vba for range of cells .but my output has `="R131C19"` instead of `=R131C19` so the function is not working 
kindly help me

[image]

```vb
Dim Fstd As Range
Dim FEDD As Range
Dim oRange As Range

Dim oFormat As FormatCondition
Set Fstd = Worksheets("Sheet2").Cells(Last_Row, 19)
Set FEDD = Worksheets("Sheet2").Cells(Last_Row, 20)
set lrow = Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1

Set oRange = Range("u" + lrow + ":" + "cl" + lrow)
oRange.FormatConditions.Delete
 Set oFormat = oRange.FormatConditions.Add(xlCellValue, xlBetween, Fstd.Address, FEDD.Address)
oFormat.Font.Color = vbRed   '.interior.color=rgb(250,100,0)
oFormat.Interior.Color = vbRed
```

Comment: what is `Fstd.` and `FEDD.` ?

Comment: please [update](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/56145559/edit) your question, don't put code in the comments. Thank you

Comment: ok .can you help me

Comment: Welcome to SO. Try concatenating `Set oFormat = oRange.FormatConditions.Add(xlCellValue, xlBetween, "=" & Fstd.Address, "=" & FEDD.Address)`.

Comment: Perfect !!!.Working great.thanks a lot